# In Sql - Should i index a two column table, when both columns are indexed everytime?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have a simple question regarding database performance.

I have a table with two columns

```
id (int) - string (varchar)
```

Is there a reason to index these two columns (or any of them)?

I use the table for count searching:

```
 SELECT count(*)  
 FROM TablaName 
 WHERE id = 'someInt' AND string = 'someString'
```

If returned count>0

do nothing

else

insert new row to the table.

The table has approx 200.000 rows and increases with around 1000 every day.

The way I see it, to index this table, will create the exact same index table, since both columns are being queried every time. So indexing is unnecessary.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: fyi: Using `EXISTS` is far more efficient if you don't actually need a precise count.

Comment: Having an index will create an **index navigation tree** "above" your actual data pages - so if your two criteria select relatively few rows, navigating through that navigation tree could potentially be orders of magnitude faster than scanning the whole table .....

Comment: @marc no there is no reason for primary key, since i dont' delete nor update.

Comment: If this is for **SQL Server** as your concrete database - there is a **huge benefit** in having a **clustered index** even on such a table! IF you don't have a clustered index, it's a *heap* (or rather: a *steaming pile of data*) with horribly bad performance numbers....

Comment: *"there is no reason for primary key"* Famous last words.

Comment: @Mike i'm wiser now then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With certain exceptions such as unique and text indexes, indexing is *not* necessary for functionality.  It is highly desirable for performance.

If you want optimal performance on this type of query, then you want a composite index on both columns: `id, string`.

If the `id` is unique (or declared to be a primary key), then the index would have a negligible effect,a and you probably would not want it.

The structure of your query, though, is suspect because of race conditions.  You might be able to get away with:

```
insert into table(. . .)
    select <values>
    where not exists (select 1 from TablaName where id = 'someInt' and string = 'someString');
```

(Note:  some databases might require a `from` clause, something like `from dual`.)

Even this might have race conditions in some databases.  To really protect the table, you should define a unique constraint on `id, string` and check for errors in the insert.

Comment: Maybe i didn't explain correctly, the id clumn is non unique. It's a number correspinding to an item clicked. So is it still needed to add indexes? or a primary key?

Comment: If the `id` is not unique, then I would recommend adding an index for performance.  If you don't care about performance, then you don't need to worry about indexes.